# Grab link from database field and use it to turn another field I've grabbed into link

Tags: javascript, php

I have a website of movie quotes. I have some php and javascript that was written by someone I paid, I don't know anything about php or javascript. The code grabs a random quote from a database and displays it on the site. It changes the quote every 10 seconds. I also have a field in the database called link which contains the link to the movie page that quote is from. I want to turn the quote into a link to that movie page. I'd appreciate any help with how to change the code to do this.

the randomquote.php file:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
header("Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8");
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT" );
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate( "D, d M Y H:i:s" ) . "GMT" );
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" );
header("Pragma: no-cache" );
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM quotes";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
$rows=$result->fetch_row();
//$rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$rndm=rand(1,$rows[0]);
$sql = "SELECT quote FROM quotes where id='".$rndm."' Limit 1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
if($result)
{
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$xml='<root>';
$xml.='<qoute>'.htmlspecialchars($row['quote']).'</qoute>';
$xml.='</root>';
echo $xml;
}
else
{
echo "Not working";
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

javascript:

```
var qouteobj=createRequestObject();
function getqoute(){
qouteobj.open("GET","/php/randomquote.php",true);
qouteobj.send(null);
qouteobj.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(qouteobj.readyState==4 && qouteobj.status==200)
{
var q_rec=qouteobj.responseText;
if (window.DOMParser)
{
parser=new DOMParser();
xmlDoc=parser.parseFromString(q_rec,"text/xml");
}
else // Internet Explorer
{
xmlDoc=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
xmlDoc.async=false;
xmlDoc.loadXML(q_rec);
}
var rq=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("qoute");
var txt="";
var i;
for (i=0;i<rq.length;i++){
txt=txt + rq[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue + "<br>";
}
document.getElementById('random-quote').innerHTML=txt;
setTimeout('getqoute()',10000);
}
}
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should contact the person who wrote that?

Comment: Yes he wants to charge me extra to do this and money is tight. And why is my post getting downvoted?

Comment: He wants to charge you extra because it's extra work. That simple.

Comment: why you ask question when you dont know php and javascript @JoeElmore

Comment: @JoeElmore Are you surprised that people want money for the work they do? - Even extra work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself. I simply updated the quote field in the database to include the link. For example:

```
<a href="http://www.bestmoviequote.com/movies/gone-with-the-wind.php">"Frankly, my dear, I don't give a damn."</a>
```

It correctly displays the link on the page. Thanks for all your help.